# Conflict between two javascript. Smooth scroll between anchors and back to top

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, conflict

I have two javascripts on my single page website.  One is meant for Smooth scrolling and the other works as "back to top".  When I test my site only one of those scripts work (the one that is called first).

Is it possible to merge both scripts into one? or how do make both scripts run with out conflict?

I don't know much about jQuery or javascript, so I am not very familiar with the .noconflict approach.

Thank you in advance for helping me out.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        // hide #back-top first
        $("#back-top").hide();

        // fade in #back-top
        $(function () {
            $(window).scroll(function () {
                if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                    $('#back-top').fadeIn();
                } else {
                    $('#back-top').fadeOut();
                }
            });

            // scroll body to 0px on click
            $('#back-top a').click(function () {
                $('body,html').animate({
                    scrollTop: 0
                }, 800);
                return false;
            });
        });

    });
    </script>

    <script> 

    var $root = $('html, body');

        $('a').click(function(){
        $root.animate({
            scrollTop: $('[name="' + $.attr(this, 'href').substr(1) + '"]').offset().top
                }, 800);
                return false;
            });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've come with a solution doing further research.

I've merged both scripts into a fully functional one:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a.anchor').click(function(){
           var anchorAttr = $(this).attr('data-title');
           var anchorPos = $('#' + anchorAttr).offset().top;

           $('html,body').stop().animate({scrollTop: anchorPos});
        });

       var backtoTop = $('.control a.backtotop');
       backtoTop.hide();  

       $(window).scroll(function () {
                if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                    backtoTop.fadeIn();
                } else {
                    backtoTop.fadeOut();
                }
            });

        backtoTop.click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('body,html').stop().animate({
                    scrollTop: 0
                }, 900);

        });

    });
```

Here is the link with the solution I was looking for:
http://jsfiddle.net/RmyxK/5/

The link above does exactly what I needed.  I think it'd be nice to share it.